# Show part of page in new window

Tags: javascript, .net, new-window

I'd like to open the page in the image below, but only showing the green part in the new window. Hiding the menu and the header to the user.

[image]

```
function openNewWindow() {
        var pr = window.open("Page.aspx", "page", "width=700, height=400");  
        pr.onload() = function() {  
            pr.document.getElementById("header").style.display = 'none';  
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to set some kind of offset for the page in the new window? Like `left:-40px` and `top:-20px` or something similar? I know `top` and `left` positions the new window rather than its content, but is there something I can do to change the position of the actual content?

Is there a work-around or another solution with the same result?

**EDIT**
When I click `<a href="javascript:openNewWindow(); return false;">Click</a>` I want Page.aspx (image above) to open in a new window, but without menu and header showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about you open a page that shows an iframe which loads your page -- and then you can set your iframe width/height to what you need and whether to provide scrolling or not?
something like this:

```
<html>
<!-- this is page2.aspx -->
<body>
<!-- header -->
<!-- menu -->
<iframe id="abc"...></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var page = ... //retrieve the value of the parameter "url" passed to us (you can find how to do this by googling)
 document.getElementById( "abc" ).src = page; //set the iframe url to the parameter passed
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

then your function becomes:

```
function openNewWindow() {
        window.open("Page.aspx?url=http://page/to/load", "page", "width=700, height=400");
}
```

Comment: I had to use an  iframe solution, nothing else worked. So I guess you get the points =)

Answer (score 1):

1. Load the whole page, but hide the header and menu using Javascript:

   ```
   newwindow.onload = function() {
       newwindow.document.getElemementById('header').style.display = 'none';
       newwindow.document.getElemementById('menu').style.display = 'none';
   }
   ```

   (or use JQuery's `.hide()` method)
2. Load the whole page, but add an extra stylesheet which sets the header and menu to hidden:

   ```
   #header, #menu {display:none !important;}
   ```
3. when you serve the page, use a different template which doesn't include the header and menu, etc. All things being equal, this would probably be the best option, but I can't really give any advice on this without knowing a whole *load* more about your code.

(all of the above assumes that you have the IDs in your header and menu that I've specified; change as appropriate)

Comment: I tried the first alternative: `var pr = window.open('Pag...` and then `pr.document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';` Felt like that should've worked, no?

Comment: @Niklas - you need to wait till the page has loaded, so put your code inside `pr.onload = function() {.....}` (I've edited the answer to show it more clearly)

Comment: I've changed the JS in my question but I guess I don't understand it all, because it still doesn't work =(

Comment: I have to unmark this answer. Can you see anything wrong with my js?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Spudley, but if that's not possible you might be able to get by with negative margins. Like this:

body { margin: -50px 0 0 -50px }